# Why my changes on partial views are not updated until rebuild?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Using .Net Core, and Vidsual Studio Community 2015, on an MVC application, if while debugging I make a simple change on my view's HTML (let's say, add an H1) and hit F5 on the browser, I see the changes reflected.

But, if I make a simple change on a partial view's HTML inside that view, and hit F5 on the browser, nothing happens.

I have to start debugging again to see the changes reflected. Is really annoying and a huge time waster.

Any idea? Am I the only one?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of .NET Core MVC are you using? Currently I'm targeting 1.0.1 ( with new csproj ) and it works fine. Did you use IISExpress or cmd boostrap to run your application? Did you try to create a new proj and do that same on that?

Comment: Hi! AspNetCore.Mvc is version 1.0.0 (in my project, created a few months ago) and I'm using IISExpress.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Weird, in my opinion, but I was including the view with the full path:

```
@Html.Partial("../Shared/_PartialViewName", Model)
```

I changed to:

```
@Html.Partial("_PartialViewName", Model)
```

And now everything works fine. Shame on you .Net Core. Shame on you.

Comment: Awh I think if you are using ~/Views/... It will work also. Partial always call your viewengine to calculate the view path.